# Хранение данных о карте в БД MySql?

Tags: php, mysql

Много раз видел на разных сайтах, что есть какое нибудь учреждение или магазин, есть кнопка "показать на карте", и он показывает на карте. Поколдовать с API yandex в принципе можно, но вот что нужно хранить в БД магазина или учреждения, что бы передать его API? Неужели банально координаты?

Comment: и каждый раз запрашивать геокодирование при вызове? Так лимит в 50 тысяч запросов в сутки быстро исчерпается. По возможности (лично моё мнение) хранить фрагмент карты на сайте и отдавать именно его.

Comment: @pavel Нет, геокодирование там не нужно делать.

Comment: Зачем запрашивать геокодирование, если у вас есть координаты? Просто ставите точку на карту и всё. Я хранил в бд около 10к точек, всё в пределах москвы, и все это нормально отображалось без всяких лимитов.

Comment: спасибо за разъяснения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Практически все методы отображение объекта хранят, как вы выразились, банально координаты.

Есть ли честно, ваш вопрос можно перефразировать в другую область (надеюсь не примете на личный счет) и задать его примерно так:

- Как отобразить длину на линейке? Неужели банально в миллиметрах?

Также в комментариях к вашему вопросу пробежала информация о так называемом геокодировании. Это тяжелые, для картографического сервиса, запросы поэтому они жестко ограничивают возможность использования подобных операций. Геокодирование бывает прямое и обратное.

Прямое геокодирование это процесс преобразования указанного имени объекта в координаты на карте.

Обратное это преобразование заданных координат в какое-то имя (дом, улица, город и т.д.)